# How do I upgrade modules to Angular 2 RC5 NgModules in a hybrid application?

Tags: angular

I have an existing [hybrid Angular 1+2 application](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) and I am having trouble following the [Angular 2 RC5 guidance in relation to the new NgModules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html). It looks as though it is intended for use with an Angular 2 RC4 application - and not a hybrid application.

In contrast to the pure RC4 scenario - no modules as they were only introduced in RC5 - I have an existing Angular 1.5 module that I need to deal with. I am guessing that I have the following options - are there any others?

1. Upgrade the existing module using the [Upgrade Adapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-with-the-upgrade-adapter). There is no mention of upgrading modules there but they were added late, so maybe the documentation is still to be updated? Or maybe we can expect support for this to be added soon?
2. Rewrite the existing module as an RC5 NgModule. Is there any guidance on how to do this?

Then there is the question of bootstrapping. I assume that a hybrid application will need to be bootstrapped with the upgrade_adapter. How do I reconcile that with the [Update your bootstrap](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) guidance which says that I should be using the platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule() function?

**Update:**
lekev87 provided a link to an example in the Angular docs which appears to have been updated to account (at least partially) for the introduction of NgModule in RC5.

As the UpgradeAdapter instance is created, a reference to an NgModule is passed in. There is however no explanation of what this will do.

```
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => MyNg2Module));
```

My guess is that the NgModule that is passed in will be used instead of the [implicitly created one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html).

```
 - We create an implicit NgModule for you as part of the bootstrap()
 - command We automatically hoist your components, pipes, and directives
```

And that it would make me responsible for looking after the second point in the list above - declaring all components etc.

Am I on the right track here?

Does this mean that while my application is a hybrid, I will need to declare everything in both my Angular 1 and Angular 2 modules?

Is there some way that I can get access to that implicitly created module instead? I am thinking that this would allow me to start from a base that has most of what I need and that I could just extend it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Hi here you can check the documentation for the  [UpgradeAdapter class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/upgrade/index/UpgradeAdapter-class.html#!#bootstrap-anchor)
You have this example:

```
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => MyNg2Module));
var module = angular.module('myExample', []);
module.directive('ng2Comp', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(Ng2));
module.directive('ng1Hello', function() {
  return {
     scope: { title: '=' },
     template: 'ng1[Hello {{title}}!](<span ng-transclude></span>)'
  };
});
@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-comp',
  inputs: ['name'],
  template: 'ng2[<ng1-hello [title]="name">transclude</ng1-hello>](<ng-content></ng-content>)',
  directives:
})
class Ng2Component {
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Ng2Component, adapter.upgradeNg1Component('ng1Hello')],
  imports: [BrowserModule]
})
class MyNg2Module {}
document.body.innerHTML = '<ng2-comp name="World">project</ng2-comp>';
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myExample']).ready(function() {
  expect(document.body.textContent).toEqual(
      "ng2[ng1[Hello World!](transclude)](project)");
});
```

Comment: OK. It looks like the docs have been at least partially updated to cover RC5. I got thrown a bit because the link to the docs you included does not include the reference to the MyNg2Module in the UpgradeAdapter constructor call. Other examples on that page did so I guess that it is an error in that example.

There is no explanation in the docs of what this does though. Is this a way of providing an override for the default NgModule that RC5 creates for you automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to introduce an NgModule using the updated [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#bootstrapping-hybrid-angular-1-2-applications). I used the following template for the new NgModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I passed a reference to it as a parameter to the constructor of the UpgradeAdapter.

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';

/* . . . */

const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(AppModule);

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], {strictDi: true});
```